# TLS handshake fails while setting a single cipher using setEnabledCipherSuites()

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, tls1.2

I am facing a strange issue, looks like JDK behaving strangely.

I have written a JAVA application, and using `setEnabledCipherSuites()` to set my preferred cipher list for TLS connection.

Strangely when I set a single cipher suit (say `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`), the TLS handshake fails. Please note, both client and server were configured to use same cipher.

However when I set a list of ciphers, at least 2 (say `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`), everything works like a charm.

Is this caused by any strange JDK issue?

Editing the question to add a clientHello here for cipher TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, however I dind't find a corresponding serverHello going out.

```
ClientHello, TLSv1.2 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1483351573 bytes = { 236, 104, 69, 5, 204, 179, 32, 84, 44, 7, 84, 102, 15, 73, 185, 254, 42, 128, 113, 217, 120, 205, 199, 195, 162, 120, 161, 41 }  Session ID:  {}  Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]  Compression Methods:  { 0 }  Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}  Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]  Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>  default-server-worker 3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 142  serverin-server-worker 0, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 142
```

The java version is 
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: Did you try the other one as the single cipher suite?

Comment: Does the server have an ECDSA key & certificate chain? Or more precisely, an EC private key and an EE certificate that authorizes that EC key for at least digitalSignature, plus any needed chain cert(s)?

Comment: @Andreas, yes I tried, same result.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I am not sure how to explicitly verify that. But, as I said if I keep atleast 2 ciphers in the list, it negotiates. So that means, server does have ECDSA key and certificate chain.

Comment: Hmmm.... Could be a bug. Did you try workaround of giving same cipher twice? You never know till you try.

Comment: Try running your Java code with the `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` command-line option.  That should generate SSL debugging information, and from that output you can see what cipher suite is actually being used.  Look for the 'Cipher Suites' item in the `ClientHello` section and the 'Cipher Suite' item in the `ServerHello` section.  See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html.

Comment: Rajat: It does not mean any such thing. ECDHE_RSA uses server RSA key&cert while ECDHE_ECDSA uses ECDSA key&cert. If client offers both ECDHE_RSA and ECDHE_ECDSA, server can choose ECDHE_RSA using RSA key&cert without having ECDSA key&cert. The only way to be certain is to look at the server keystore and see what is in it. That depends partly on what kind of keystore the server uses and where it is, which is turn usually depends on what kind of server it is.

Comment: @LukeWoodward :  thanks man, for suggesting debug option. It really helped me to gain some insight.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for your comments. My bad looks like its not the issue what I described above. I could see if I set TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 as a single cipher, things just work fine. However if set any of TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 or TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 , as a single cipher, negotiation fails. But as I said strangly, if enable both of these ciphers, I could see TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 gets negotiated.

Comment: Did you really mean GCM there, or CBC? Assuming CBC as in original Q, I can't reproduce; with Oracle 8.05 and 8.102 (the oldest and newest I have to hand) configuring both ECDHE_{RSA,ECDSA} always works and configuring single ECDHE_{percert} always works. If you have a server trace from javax.net.debug showing the problem (server because it sees both the keystore and the hello) please add to your Q, with your java version(s). Preferably also give minimal code, although personally I _think_ I have understood your description adequately.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Sorry for delayed response, was not keeping well, hence was away from work. Thanks for all the details and help. Being new to it please pardon my ignorance. However what I understood so far was, you can ONLY negotiate ciphers which are presents in keystore being used. When I tried to list them(using `keytool -list -keystore`) I could see only 2 certs. Will try to use JDK's keystore and see if this issue persist.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: How to find out what and all keys and certs are available in keystore? A `keytool -list -keystore` command gives me following   `Your keystore contains 2 entries

custome_ca, Jan 12, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): BC:B5:05:DC:A4:49:A3:C4:1A:BC:B3:0C:37:85:54:A4:A7:7D:9A:C9
1, Jan 12, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 15:4D:E3:C0:05:CA:28:4F:8A:A1:0B:BE:48:80:AA:6D:BD:65:B3:41`   How to find which cipher its representing ?

Comment: I have edited the question to add a client hello and java version, as suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: (1) An asymmetric key (in keystore or elsewhere) has an algorithm such as RSA, not 'ciphers' in the TLS meaning (actually cipher_suites_).. For a server only the PrivateKeyEntry matters. If you have OpenSSL do `keytool -keystore filename -exportcert -alias 1 -rfc | openssl x509 -noout -text` and look at the line(s) just after `Subject Public Key Info:`. Otherwise it depends on your system; e.g. on Windows do the `keytool -exportcert` part redirected to a file with extension `.cer` then doubleclick it and go to Details and look at the line for Public key.

Comment: (2) Please try to preserve linebreaks in log-data you post, it's more readable or at least less unreadable. There has to be more to the trace than that. If the negotiation is failing there probably is NOT a ServerHello. For JSSE error cases often there will be an alert instead of the ServerHello, sometimes preceded directly by something that indicates the cause, but the data about the cause might be spread out and might be earlier even before the ClientHello.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Hey Dave, this JDK bug confirms you reasoning, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133741 . Thanks for all the help.